# Spring-batch job randomly throws different exit statuses among FAILED and COMPLETED

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Here are the configurations of a spring-batch project.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" }
}

dependencies {

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-core', version: '5.1.3.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.1.3.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-web', version: '5.1.3.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.1.3.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-core
    compile group: 'org.springframework.batch', name: 'spring-batch-core', version: '4.1.0.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-infrastructure
    compile group: 'org.springframework.batch', name: 'spring-batch-infrastructure', version: '4.1.0.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.batch/spring-batch-test
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.batch', name: 'spring-batch-test', version: '4.1.0.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.9.1'

    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.6'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-core', version: '2.9.7'

}
```

Job configuration:

```
<batch:job id="batchUpdateJob" job-repository="jobRepository">
    <batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
        <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader=“reader1”
                writer="compositeWriter" processor=“processor1” commit-interval="10" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader=“reader2”
                writer=“writer2” processor=“processor2” commit-interval="10" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

main() where the batch job is run:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Loading The Bean Definition From The Spring Configuration File
    contextObj = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(springConfig);
    jobObj = (Job) contextObj.getBean(JOB_NAME);
    jobLauncherObj = (JobLauncher) contextObj.getBean(JOB_LAUNCHER_NAME);
    try {
        JobParametersBuilder jobBuilder = new JobParametersBuilder();
        JobExecution execution = jobLauncherObj.run(jobObj, jobParameters);
        System.out.println("Exit Status : " + execution.getStatus());
    } catch (Exception exceptionObj) {
        exceptionObj.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Done");
}
```

For each run of the main(), the `exitStatus` of the job executed is either `COMPLETED` or `FAILED`, though no change to the project is made in between the runs.

And when the exit status is `FAILED`, the `stepExecutions` has the following trace:

> [StepExecution: id=1, version=2, name=step1, status=FAILED, exitStatus=FAILED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.reader1’ defined in class path resource [spring/batch/jobs/spring-beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584)
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113)
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>          at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
>          at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:193)
>          at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.open(Unknown Source)
>          at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144)
>          at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>          at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137)
>          at com.simba.tool.cacheserver.batchprocess.App.main(App.java:39)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>          at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
>          at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604)
>          at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219)
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1653)
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
>          at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
>          ... 22 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>          at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:299)
>          at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585)
>          ... 28 more
>       ]

Bean defining both the readers are configured like this:

```
    <bean id="reader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="template" ref="mongoTemplate" />
        <property name="collection" value="Collection" />
        <property name="targetType" value="com.example.SomeObject" />
        <property name="query" value="{ $and : [  { 'Field1': /.*#{jobParameters['Param1']}.*/ }, { 'Field2': { $gte: ISODate('9999-12-30T00:00:00Z') } }, { 'Field3': { '$eq': 'Open' } } ] }" />
        <property name="sort">
            <util:map>
                 <entry key="Field4" value="#{T(org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction).ASC}" /> 
            </util:map>
        </property>
        <property name="fields" value="{ 'Field5': 1, 'Field6': 1, 'Field7': 1 }" />
    </bean>
```

Previous research:

My search on the exception message: `Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query’` did not fetch any relevant results.
The research using keywords like the ones in the title of this question did not shed much light either.

Why does the execution of the batch job fail sometimes and finish other times? What is the fix for this?

---

Update:
Tried changing the definition of the readers to this:

```
<bean id="query" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="your json query here"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader">
    <property name="query" ref="query"/>
    <!-- define other properties of the reader here -->
</bean>
```

Now ended up with the following trace:

> [StepExecution: id=1, version=2, name=step1, status=FAILED, exitStatus=FAILED, readCount=0, filterCount=0, writeCount=0 readSkipCount=0, writeSkipCount=0, processSkipCount=0, commitCount=0, rollbackCount=0, exitDescription=org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.reader' defined in class path resource [spring/batch/jobs/spring-beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,java.lang.CharSequence,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,java.lang.CharSequence,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.StepScope.get(StepScope.java:113)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>           at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:193)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.open(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemStream.open(CompositeItemStream.java:103)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.open(TaskletStep.java:311)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:200)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:68)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:67)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:169)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:144)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:136)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:313)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:144)
>           at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:137)
>           at com.simba.tool.cacheserver.batchprocess.App.main(App.java:41)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,java.lang.CharSequence,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,java.lang.CharSequence,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>           at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)
>           at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertForProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:604)
>           at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:219)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1697)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1653)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1400)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
>           ... 22 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19 implementing java.io.Serializable,java.lang.Comparable,java.lang.CharSequence,org.springframework.aop.scope.ScopedObject,org.springframework.aop.framework.AopInfrastructureBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised,org.springframework.core.DecoratingProxy' to required type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query' for property 'query': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
>           at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:299)
>           at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:585)
>           ... 28 more
>       ]

Comment: Can you please share your mongo item reader configuration and tell which Spring Batch version do you use?

Comment: Apologies for forgetting to add the item reader configuration. Edited the question to add that.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question with the config of the reader. Which Spring Batch version do you use? There was a change made to the `MongoItemReader` between v3 and v4 and I need to know which version do you use to help you.

Comment: The project uses version 4.1.0.RELEASE of `spring-batch-core` and version 2.1.3.RELEASE of `spring-data-mongodb`.

Comment: ok in that case, my answer should fix your issue since it explicitly defines a bean of type String for your query and refers to it in the reader. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah, tried it out. But since I have to use job parameters to construct the query string, I don't know how to do that in the `query` bean. Tried changing scope of it to `step`, but then got `ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19` exception, so I think that's not the right way to go...

Comment: Making the query bean as step scoped is the way to go in order to use late-binding of a a job parameter in the query. Please post the full stacktrace or share a project on github or somewhere else and I will try to help you on it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full stack trace after I tried the fix that you suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are two `setQuery` methods in `MongoItemReader`: [`setQuery(Query)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemReader.java#L106) and [`setQuery(String)`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/data/MongoItemReader.java#L128). So when configured with XML, there might be an ambiguity on which one to use. In your case, it looks like Spring is trying to convert your `String` query into a `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query` object and it does not find a converter for that.

You need to specify which type of query to use and set it on the reader.

In your example, you need to configure the query and the reader with something like:

```
<bean id="query" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="your json query here"/>
</bean>

<bean id="mongoItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader">
    <property name="query" ref="query"/>
    <!-- define other properties of the reader here -->
</bean>
```

Hope this helps.